# Using allocators

Tags: c++, allocator

Are these versions of **new** and **delete** are exception safe? Any possible pitfalls?

Assume that **customized_allocator_type** is STL compatible. Also assume that the allocator's constructor doesn't have any side effect and all instances are equivalent.

Thanks in advance for your input!

```
template <typename T>
inline T * customized_new(const T& t)
{
    customized_allocator_type<T> alloc;
    T * ptr = alloc.allocate(1);

    if (ptr==0)
        throw std::bad_alloc();

    try {
        alloc.construct(ptr, t);
    } catch (...) {
        alloc.deallocate(ptr, 1);
        throw;
    }

    return ptr;
}


template <typename T>
inline void customized_delete(T * ptr)
{
    if (ptr==0)
        return;

    customized_allocator_type<T> alloc;
    alloc.destroy(ptr);
    alloc.deallocate(ptr, 1);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (at best) redundant:

```
if (ptr==0)
    throw std::bad_alloc();
```

If `customized_allocator_type` is meeting the standard library allocator requirements then it must raise an exception if storage could not be obtained. Returning null from `allocate` would not be correct.

Comment: Agreed. STL compliant allocator shouldn't return null. I mark your answer as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the behavior of customized_allocator_type's construct() function is known that it doesn't deallocate the memory on exception, then your solution is good.

Note: there is a typo in customized_delete() check for null pointer - it should be:

```
if (ptr == 0)
  return;
```